# import fs.default.cp Sync is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, turborepo

Tried to install TurboRepo, but after selecting npm got this error.

```
   >>> TURBOREPO

>>> Welcome to Turborepo! Let's get you set up with a new codebase.

? Where would you like to create your turborepo? ./my-turborepo
? Which package manager do you want to use? npm

Aborting installation.
Unexpected error. Please report it as a bug:   
TypeError: import_fs.default.cpSync is not a function
    at run (C:\Users\singh.yogesh\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_npx\5504\node_modules\create-turbo\dist\index.js:338:21)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
```

Answer (score 6):

if you upgrade to node version 16, this error won't appear.

Comment: Explain why with references to official documentation / changelogs.